# How to copy files before deletion / Recycle bin in android?

Tags: android, c++, linux-kernel, android-ndk

I'm making an application that works as an Recycle Bin.

What I've done till now.

- Service using fileobserver
- Watching full sdcard
- Copy / Move File Methods
- Copy Files / Detect File Operations in C++ (NDK). // Mostly in Deadlock Condition.
- After some Research I've found that inotify.h is used in cpp to detect file operation.
- i have written code to use inotify.h in my project.

Problems :

- If i use android File Observer methods then i am getting notified after file deletion and getting FileNotFoundException.
- If i use Native Code i mean CPP/NDK for this when i try to call native method my application just doesn't respond. it doesn't even give any error or anything just it seems like deadlock.

After so many tries i am not able to achieve anything. So if any linux-kernel or android expert can guide me for this application that would be great.

EDIT :

I have tried some methods for linux kernel and executed in ubuntu it works fine.
But when i try to do the same to android it doesn't work.

- if i need to override delete method from linux kernel or in android then how can i do that?

If you want to see my function and other stuff. please help me out.

Comment: you cannot do what you want unless you overwrite java.io.File#delete() method

Comment: Hmm. Thanks Let me try that.

Comment: can anyone give me hint?